# Can WebGrease minify and bundle .less files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, less, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to implement minification and bundling into an AspNet MVC 3 project using WebGrease.  I know WebGrease can minify and bundle .js and .css files but can it be used for .less files also?

Comment: Bueller Bueller Bueller, anyone, anyone, anyone??

Comment: I haven't used WebGrease yet but if you have Visual Studio 2012 why don't you use the 'Web Essentials 2012' extension? You can configure the extension to automatically create a (minified) css file when you save your .less file.

Answer (score 0):

after doing a bit of testing it seems that yes it will minify less files with no problems

Comment: But can it bundle the files?